# Differentiate 'Could not allocate space for object' Exception

Tags: java, sql-server, exception

I am getting 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not allocate space for object
as filegroup is full. 
I want a way to identify this SQL exception from other SQL Exceptions.

If I check java.sql.SQLException.venderCode == 1105 will that be enough?And is there any place I can get the description of the 1105 code?

Comment: `select * from sys.sysmessages where error = 1105`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I check java.sql.SQLException.venderCode == 1105 will that be enough?

Yes, that vendor code (available by calling `getErrorCode()`) will always map to that error. Just bear in mind it's specific to SQL Server rather than consistent across all SQL implementations.

[Various sites like this one](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/index.aspx) detail all the error codes available for SQL server (including 1105.)

Comment: How do I know same venderCode for oracle? Is there such code?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the error code alone is sufficient for your need. The returned `vendorCode` is the SQL Server error number. SQL Server errors and the tokenized message text can be retrieved by the `sys.messages` DMV. Example for the US English language:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.messages
WHERE
    message_id = 1105
    AND language_id = 1033;
```